# Error in rmse(., truth = variable, estimate = .pred) : unused arguments (truth = , estimate = .pred) in R Tidymodels (yardstick)

Tags: r, tidyverse, decision-tree, tidymodels, yardstick

I am Fitting a regression tree model, using this `Tidymodels` [tutorial](https://emilhvitfeldt.github.io/ISLR-tidymodels-labs/tree-based-methods.html).

```
# Create a specification
tree_spec <- decision_tree() %>% set_engine("rpart")
```

```
# Create an engine
reg_tree_spec <- tree_spec %>% set_mode("regression")
```

```
# Fit the model
reg_tree_fit <- fit(reg_tree_spec, loan_amount ~ ., kenya_data_df_train)

# Print
reg_tree_fit
```

parsnip model object

Fit time:  2.5s
n= 56868

node), split, n, deviance, yval
* denotes terminal node

1. root 56868 32009190000   455.2222
2. lender_count< 728.5 56859 13948640000   448.2417
3. lender_count< 81.5 56613  6692397000   428.2886
4. lender_count< 20.5 47772  2345794000   342.4569
5. lender_count< 12.5 35164  1238679000   282.1622 *
6. lender_count>=12.5 12608   622737900   510.6202 *
7. lender_count>=20.5 8841  2092969000   892.0767
8. lender_count< 38.5 7455   740153600   787.4748 *
9. lender_count>=38.5 1386   832502400  1454.7080 *
10. lender_count>=81.5 246  2046660000  5040.1420
11. lender_count< 229 224   938017600  4421.3170 *
12. lender_count>=229 22   149470700 11340.9100 *
13. lender_count>=728.5 9   554222200 44555.5600 *

**But I receive a weird error when I use test data.**

```
# Evaluate on test data
augment(reg_tree_fit, new_data = kenya_data_df_test) %>%
  rmse(truth = loan_amount, estimate = .pred)
```

```
Error in rmse(., truth = loan_amount, estimate = .pred) : 
unused arguments (truth = loan_amount, estimate = .pred)
```

My `dput()` example for train data:

```
structure(list(loan_amount = 200, term_in_months = 14, lender_count = 8, 
sector_Agriculture = 1L, sector_Arts = 0L, sector_Clothing = 0L, 
sector_Construction = 0L, sector_Education = 0L, sector_Entertainment = 0L, 
sector_Food = 0L, sector_Health = 0L, sector_Housing = 0L, 
sector_Manufacturing = 0L, sector_Personal_Use = 0L, sector_Retail = 0L, 
sector_Services = 0L, sector_Transportation = 0L, sector_Wholesale = 0L, 
repayment_interval_bullet = 0L, repayment_interval_irregular = 0L, 
repayment_interval_monthly = 1L, repayment_interval_weekly = 0L, 
gender_both = 0L, gender_female = 1L, gender_male = 0L, gender_NA = 0L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x000001d8b6f91ef0>)
```

`dput()` for test data.

```
structure(list(loan_amount = 250, term_in_months = 14, lender_count = 
1, 
sector_Agriculture = 0L, sector_Arts = 0L, sector_Clothing = 0L, 
sector_Construction = 0L, sector_Education = 0L, sector_Entertainment 
= 0L, 
sector_Food = 0L, sector_Health = 0L, sector_Housing = 0L, 
sector_Manufacturing = 0L, sector_Personal_Use = 0L, sector_Retail = 
0L, 
sector_Services = 1L, sector_Transportation = 0L, sector_Wholesale = 
0L, 
repayment_interval_bullet = 0L, repayment_interval_irregular = 1L, 
repayment_interval_monthly = 0L, repayment_interval_weekly = 0L, 
gender_both = 0L, gender_female = 1L, gender_male = 0L, gender_NA = 
0L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = 
<pointer: 0x000001d8b6f91ef0>)
```

Comment: @akrun, I added for test data too

Comment: For me, it is not giving an error with the new data i.e. `augment(reg_tree_fit, new_data = kenya_data_df_test) %>% rmse(truth = loan_amount, estimate = .pred)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  .metric .estimator .estimate
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 rmse    standard          50`

Comment: @akrun, super weird. I will try again. Thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: Please check if the `packageVersion('tidymodels')#[1] ‘0.1.3’` are different

Comment: @akrun, it is 0.1.3

Comment: Then, not sure.  Perhaps, function masking?  try to use `packagename::functionname` to avoid that

Comment: @akrun, `yardstick::rmse` fixed the issue, thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with `akrun`'s answer above - `yardstick::rmse()` gave the necessary result.